# Java Desktop.open(File f) reference file within JAR?

Tags: java, jar, desktop

It is possible to for `Desktop.open(File f)` to reference a file located within a JAR?

I tried using `ClassLoader.getResource(String s)`, converting it to a URI, then creating a File from it. But this results in `IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical`.

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(...);
System.out.println("url=" + url);    // url is valid
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(url.toURI()));
```

A possibility is [the answer at JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/456579/Java-General/java/open-pdf-file-located-inside), which is to create a temporary file from the resource within the JAR – not very elegant.

This is running on Windows XP.

Comment: Actually the creation of a temporary file is a good workaround. You can create an "elegant" library for that, so you don't have to code it each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Files" inside .jar files are not files to the operating system. They are just some area of the .jar file and are usually compressed. They are not addressable as separate files by the OS and therefore can't be displayed this way.

Java itself has a neat way to referring to those files by some URI (as you realized by using `getResource()`) but that's entirely Java-specific.

If you want some external application to access that file, you've got two possible solutions:

1. Provide some standardized way to access the file or
2. Make the application able to address files that are packed in a .jar (or .zip) file.

Usually 2 is  not really an option (unless the other application is also written in Java, in which case it's rather easy).

Option 1 is usually done by simply writing to a temporary file and referring to that. Alternatively you could start a small web server and provide the file via some URL.

Comment: I actually do have a web server (Jetty) embedded in the application. Then problem is Desktop.browse(URI) will only launch a browser and not an application.

Comment: @Kuo: yes, I realized you asked about open() after I added my edit. Of course for open() only the temp file solution is useful.

Answer (score 3):

A resource within a jar file simply *isn't* a file - so you can't use a `File` to get to it. If you're using something which really needs a file, you will indeed have to create a temporary file and open that instead.

Answer (score 1):

But an entry in a JAR file is **not a `File`**! The JAR file is a file; its entries are JAR-file entries (to state the obvious).

Java contains abstractions that mean you don't necessarily need to work with `File`s - why not use a `Reader` or `InputStream` to encapsulate the input?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not, because as you just witness you don't have a valid file in first place

From the article: [Using the Desktop API in Java SE 6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/) we got

> ***OPEN:*** Represents an open action performed by an application associated with opening a specific file type

So you would have to have a valid file and then have an application associated with that file so the OS can open it.  While such app may exist you still have to make it understand the URL to your file.