# Java how to load resource in exported jar using URL

Tags: java, url, io

I need to load a resource using a URL in a exported jar. So far I've tried this:

```
private Sound loadSound(String path) {
    URL url = GameSound.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path);
    Sound s = TinySound.loadSound(url);
    return s;
}
```

But the URL doesn't work after I export the jar. I have put my files that I need to be loaded into the src folder of my project. How can I do this?

Comment: what is the code for TinySound.loadSound()?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556187/java-desktop-openfile-f-reference-file-within-jar

Comment: Sorry, TinySound is a library I am using that I found, I didn't make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getClass().getResource(path)` can use an absolute path of the form "/....". The `ClassLoader.getResource(path)` uses an absolute path without a leading slash: "xyz/abc/uvw`.

The other problem is using the classloader responsible for that jar. Your `GameSound` should best reside in the same external jar.`.

---

***Problem:*** in src it works in a jar not:

When having just one jar, check with 7zip or WinZip the file path in the jar. Especially paths in jars and on non-Windows systems are **case-sensitive**.

For `/a/b/c/d.png` one can use:

```
a.b.MyClass.getResource("c/d.png");
e.f.MyClass.getResource("/a/b/c/d.png");
```

Where MyClass resides in the same jar.

The second cause might be that the using class internally expects a `file://` or `http://` URL. That would simply be utterly bad API design.

Comment: But GameSound does reside in the same jar? And which class loader should I use?

Comment: Then `GameSound.class.getResource("/"+path)` should do. Check that `loadSound` is not restricted to the protocol `file://` but can deal with `jar:` too. Move the original jar without external jar elsewhere and run it.

Comment: What do you mean move the original jar? TinySound is a library that I found for playing OGG files, and I package it into my game using JarSplice.